# JQuery - Get the correct SELECTED-value by click of button when two buttons are in two separate forms using ONE function

Tags: jquery

I deleted my last question from yesterday, and I have read to understand what to ask. So here I go again:

I am trying to get my script to get the correct value from the select, based on which button is clicked.

I have the following small redirecting script:

```
  (function($){
      // bind change event to select
      $("#button1,#button2").on('click', function () {
          var url =  $("#form-field-dynamic_select :selected").val();// get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
  })(jQuery);
```

I have this html:

FORM 1:

```
<select name="form_fields[dynamic_select]" id="form-field-dynamic_select" class="elementor-class">
<option value="https://www.example.com/page1">Example 1</option>
<option value="https://www.example.com/page2">Example 2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="elementor-button" id="button1">
```

FORM 2:

```
<select name="form_fields[dynamic_select]" id="form-field-dynamic_select" class="elementor-class">
<option value="https://www.example.com/page3">Example 3</option>
<option value="https://www.example.com/page4">Example 4</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="elementor-button" id="button2">
```

The way this works as of now, is that in FORM 1 - it works like it should, but in FORM 2 - it redirects to /page2 on both selects.

How can I get it so on FORM 2, it also redirects correctly to /page3 and /page4 if those selects are selected by user?

I am brand new to this, so feel free to explain how I need to think :)

**EDIT**

What I do understand is that my *form-field-dynamic_select* should be unique for each form, and so it should be different in the var URL, and I have played around with getElementByID(), but I just could not get that right.

If necessary for a modification on the script, I am able to rename the second select ID to something else.

Comment: On the same page, two elements don't have the same id, it's wrong, id is always unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.closest("form")` to get form where button has been clicked and then using `.find()` & `.val()` get select-box value.

***Demo code*** :

```js
(function($) {
  $("#button1,#button2").on('click', function() {
    //use `this` (current button refernce) get form then slect value 
    var url = $(this).closest("form").find("select").val();
    if (url) {
      //window.location = url; // redirect
      console.log(url)
    }
    return false;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FORM 1:
<form>
  <select name="form_fields[dynamic_select]" class="elementor-class">
    <option value="https://www.example.com/page1">Example 1</option>
    <option value="https://www.example.com/page2">Example 2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="elementor-button" id="button1">Click1</button>
</form>
FORM 2:
<form>
  <select name="form_fields[dynamic_select]" class="elementor-class">
    <option value="https://www.example.com/page3">Example 3</option>
    <option value="https://www.example.com/page4">Example 4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="elementor-button" id="button2">Click2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you  very much! This works, but I had to change back to window.location = url; for it to redirect at all

Comment: Yes , i have commented that out because you will not get to see console result :) then

Comment: Oh.. Hehe, well then I get it. Thanks. I noticed I did not get any errors in my chrome developer tools. I did of course not understand it meant it would show the code on the screen here as an example. That's how fresh I am :p

Comment: You will be able to see result of console in your browser console tab . Let me now if still have any doubt in above code :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename the second select id to something else. Also you could try this

```
(function($){
      // bind change event to select
      $("#button1").on('click', function () {
          var url =  $("#form-field-dynamic_select :selected").val();// get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              console.log(url);
              //window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
      $("#button2").on('click', function () {
          var url =  $("#form-field-dynamic_select1 :selected").val();// get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              console.log(url);
              //window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works perfectly, and It's very logical for me to understand as being so new to javascript. However, why did you change  window.location = url; to console.log(url); ? This did not work, it looks like my page needs the window.location = url; to work. What's the diffference?

Comment: I used it for debugging purpose so you could understand and see the value in browser console.

Comment: I get it :) Thank you :)